# cs50 resize (less comfortable) issue

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working cs50 pset4, resize (less comfortable) I'm trying to write a program that can resize an image by a factor n of user input, its close to working, it rescales horizontally but not vertically. I believe the problem is to in these sets of loops, does anyone know how to fix this.

```
    for (int i=0; i< abs(bi.biHeight); i++)
    {
    for (int l=0; l<n; l++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<bi.biWidth; j++) {

            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
            // write RGB triple to outfile
            fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < Npadding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }

    }
    }
    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask on https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to store the whole resized horiszontal line and write that line n times to the output file. In your code you just write the resized horizontal lines once to the output file, so it's normal that there is no vertical resizing.

Comment: When you loop over `l` you consume a new line from infile for each iteration instead of using the same line. While storing the line as Michael Walz suggests, is more efficient, you could also try to use `fseek` to read the line from infile again.